# Angular2 - model driven forms using CSS ng-valid styling breaks

Tags: angular, css-selectors, angular2-template, angular2-forms

The angular2 tutorial for Template Driven forms [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) uses the following CSS:

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

It's a nice style indicator but if you use it for a Domain Driven form, only the red state (`ng-invalid`) works. Once a required field is valid, it does not turn green.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iF2ohF?p=preview)

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: your plunkr is full of errors. Check the console

Comment: thanks, errors fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from Stefan's answer, this solves the issue:

```
.ng-valid:not(form), .ng-valid.required {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}
```

[Plunkr with fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/ww5sj8?p=preview).